# dump per process stack in linux

Tags: process, linux-kernel, stack-trace

I need to dump the each and every process stack in linux kernel when the system hangs.

I am currently trying to implement in one of my kernel module based on the watchdog timer timeout.
Watchdog timer is reset by a user daemon for every timeslice. 
When the system hangs, there's no one up to reset the timer.
Hence it expires and generates an interrupt.
I wrote an interrupt handler where I should dump the stack of every process running.

So, my question is how can I dump stack of every process in kernel?

Thanks
Venkatesh

Comment: If the system is hung, how will your module or kernel function will run? And how are you going to detect such case (i.e. system is hung)?
Anyways, you can look at one of those process check-pointing projects (e.g. Berkeley Lab C/R) and iterate over the list of processes in the system.

Answer (score 0):

show_state() (include/linux/sched.h) will do this for you. BTW, this function is already available from the sysrq handler, which you might be able to make use of if it's enabled. See Documentation/sysrq.txt

Also, there are some other kernel debugging options you might be able to enable to help find your problem. Check out the Kernel Hacking menu in make menuconfig. In particular, CONFIG_LOCKUP_DETECTOR ("Detect Hard and Soft Lockups" in the menu) might be helpful.

Comment: The show_state() dumps the stack trace in hexdump.
crond         S 802BED8C     0   673      1           731   669 (NOTLB)

Stack : 81284000 00030002 2acec120 00000000 83d1d1e4 00420000 fffd4735 0000d6d9

        83d63ed8 80310000 7fe0f980 386d43bd 0000003a 00420000 00000012 802bed8c

How can I get the function trace

Comment: Hmm.... looks like you need to have enabled CONFIG_KALLSYMS in order to get the function name.

Comment: Also, if we enable CONFIG_KALLSYMS, it only provide with the kernel symbols. Is there any way to see the stack dump of the function calls of the application(userspace).

Comment: Run the process under gdb, or enable cores to be created (see the ulimit command) and look at the core file with gdb after a crash. (If you have a kernel panic/oops/hang, of course, it's unlikely you'll get a core file.)

Comment: My purpose is to check the trace for all the processes as I am not sure which process is causing the hang.
Hence gdb for each process cant be possible.
Is there any other way to print the stack trace of all processes